Django Project "failed to install application dependencies" On Elastic Beanstalk
My coworker and I are attempting to upload a website we have been working on to AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
We have tried using both console & command line techniques to create the instance and in both cases it ends with the 4 errors:
Instance deployment failed to install application dependencies. The deployment failed.
Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
[Instance: i-0deb02382df3b0fd9] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
Create environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.
Neither of us have experience with working with AWS before, and we spent several hours attempting to find solutions to this and nothing has worked.
Our Django project has a Requirements.txt file, and a .ebextensions folder with a django.config file inside.
enter image description here
Contents of the django.config file:
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: GMIFY.wsgi:application

Contents of the requirements.txt file: (made by doing pip freeze > requirements.txt)
asgiref==3.7.2
awsebcli==3.21.0
botocore==1.35.34
cement==2.10.14
certifi==2024.8.30
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
colorama==0.4.6
Django==5.0.3
django-extensions==3.2.3
idna==3.10
jmespath==1.0.1
numpy==2.0.0
pandas==2.2.2
pathspec==0.10.1
psycopg2-binary==2.9.9
pypiwin32==223
python-dateutil==2.9.0.post0
pytz==2024.1
pywin32==307
PyYAML==6.0.2
requests==2.32.3
semantic-version==2.10.0
setuptools==75.1.0
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.4
termcolor==2.5.0
tzdata==2024.1
urllib3==1.26.20
wcwidth==0.2.13
whitenoise==6.6.0

We have tried accessing the logs, but there was no clear line(s) indicating what the error is.
If you need anymore of the code please let me know.
What we tried:
Using AWS Console Elastic Beanstalk "Create Environment"
Uploading the zip file
Using command line
eb init
eb create
Expected Outcome:
A hosted website running our code
Actual result:
A running instance with Severe health and a "502 Bad Gateway" along with the 4 errors described above.
